# K8S ingress-nginx EXTERNAL_IP remains <pending> forever

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

We use local K8S cluster for development in our company and the first step after fresh install (or reset) of K8S is to install `ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx` of version `3.34.0` and wait for it to have `EXTERNAL_IP` to be set to `localhost`. It's ok for my colleagues, but for me it's stuck forever in `<pending>` state like this:

```
$ kubectl get all
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-5f6d7594cd-whlp4   1/1     Running   0          5m30s

NAME                                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.107.79.231   <pending>     80:30701/TCP,443:30433/TCP   5m30s
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.101.145.39   <none>        443/TCP                      5m30s
service/kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      6m57s

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           5m30s

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-5f6d7594cd   1         1         1       5m30s
```

And it has been so for hours, almost a day. Tried resetting cluster, restarting Docker, different versions of `ingress-nginx`, restarting mac - no use. It must have this external ip, otherwise when we deploy our application locally, we can't access it.

OS: macOS Ventura 13.2.1 (arm, m2)

Docker version:
[image]

**SOLUTION:** The only solution I've found is to reset Docker Desktop to defaults from Troubleshoot menu option.

Comment: You _really_ should update DockerDesktop first. The version you have installed is outdated, to put it mildly.

Comment: I cannot. This is the version used in our company and we are forced to use it.

Comment: The LoadBalancer Service's "external IP" field doesn't necessarily get set, particularly using developer-oriented Kubernetes setups.  Can you connect to your application anyways, maybe using `localhost` and the 30xxx port number?